# Natural deduction introduction and elimination rules for modal quantifiers

Tags: logic, reference-request, modal-logic

I've read several papers on modal natural deduction but I've only been able to find one clear explanation of []-Introduction (`[]A` if `A` can be proved from no assumptions/premises). But there were no separate rules for <>-Introduction. Instead `<>A` was defined as `~[]~A`. And there were no rules for quantifier elimination at all.

For aesthetic reasons I'd prefer to work in a logic where all symbols are defined primitively and their correspondences are results, and where we cannot manipulate terms in the scope of a quantifier.

Is there a formalization of modal logic of this sort? What are its introduction and elimination rules? Are there any papers on it?

Comment: <> introduction/elimination are described on [Cogburn's blog](http://www.newappsblog.com/2011/07/fitch-style-proper-natural-deduction-formulation-of-modal-system-k.html). For quantifiers see ch.12 of [Garson's book](https://books.google.es/books?id=0dnqAQAAQBAJ&hl=es&source=gbs_navlinks_s).

Comment: I can't access the book, but the blog is great! If you post this as an answer, maybe with a small summary, I would accept it in a heartbeat.

Comment: Thanks, but not my cup of tea. Since you seem excited perhaps you could post a self-answer summary. For the book try [this link](http://en.booksee.org/book/1190846).

Comment: You can see: David Siemens, [FITCH-STYLE RULES FOR MANY MODAL LOGICS](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ndjfl/1093888133), *NDJFL* (1977)

Comment: Maybe also the "original": Frederic Brenton Fitch, [Symbolic Logic: An Introduction](https://books.google.it/books?id=a3wIAQAAIAAJ), Ronald Press (1952)

Comment: For a recent overview: Andrzej Indrzejczak, [Natural Deduction, Hybrid Systems and Modal Logics](https://books.google.it/books?id=63r-8xK0Q8EC&printsec=frontcover), Springer (2010).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Garson's *Modal Logic for Philosophers* (link in comments above):

First we introduce a new kind of subproof, a *boxed subproof*. It contains no assumptions and is marked by `[]` at its start, as in

```
| presmises
|---
| stuff
|| []
||---
|| other stuff
| more stuff
```

You can't reiterate into a boxed subproof, so the following is invalid:

```
| Q
|---
|| []
||---
|| Q R   (BAD! NO! DON'T!)
```

That would obviously be fallacious---going from "is the case" to "necessarily the case".

Now for the inference rules. []-Introduction:

```
| []
|---
| .
| .
| .
| Q
------ []I
[]Q
```

There's a `[]`-elimination rule, too. It's the exception to the no-reiterating thing and it goes like this:

```
| []Q
|| []
||---
------ []E
|| Q
```

Note that this isn't *really* elimination, not in the normal way we think about it. What you'd really expect is something like `[]Q -> Q`, but this is actually an axiom added to K to make system T.

Now Garson defines `<>Q := ~[]~Q`, but I want to be able to introduce and eliminate it primitively. Garson provides a derived rule for `<>`-elimination:

```
<>P
| []
|---
|| P
|| .
|| .
|| .
|| Q
------ <>E
<>Q
```

Which can be summed-up as

```
<>P
[](P -> Q)
------ <>E
<>Q
```

---

I haven't been able to find an inference rule for `<>`-introduction. It now seems to me that no such rule is possible, because there is no a priori way of discovering whether or not a formal statement is merely possible. This stands in contrast to necessity---we know a priori that every statement provable in nonmodal logic is necessary.

Comment: What did you find out about a <>-introduction rule? I share your aesthetic tastes and would prefer to have [] and <> primitive too, and am curious if it's possible.

Comment: @Adam, I didn't keep looking for too long, but I never found anything. : (

Comment: It looks like your <> elimination rule is *also* a <> introduction rule; and they cannot be seperrated. You are eliminating <>P and introducing <>Q, via deriving Q under a boxed-context  assumption of P.